# Error con LoginController personalizado

Tags: laravel

Bueno he estado personalizando el LoginController que viene por defecto en Laravel, el RegisterController tambien lo personalice sin problemas, pero el LoginController no permite logear, aqui mi codigo:
-LoginController:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Trabajador;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

protected $redirectTo = '/';

public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('guest', ['only'=>'showLoginForm']);
    }

public function showLoginForm(){
        return view('auth.login');
    }

public function login(Request $request){
        $credentials = $this->validate(request(),[
            $this->username()=>'email|required|string',
            'contra'=>'required|string'
        ]);
if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
         return 'has iniciado sesion';
        }else{
        return 'NO INICIO SESION';
  }
}

public function logout(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }

public function username(){
        return 'correo';
    }

public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return 'contra';
    }

}
```

Mi Modelo:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

class Trabajador extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{   
    use Authenticatable;

    public $table = 'Trabajadores';
    protected $primaryKey = 'IdTrabajador';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'correo', 'contra',
    ];

    public function getAuthPassword()
        {
            return $this->contra;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás llamando a validar a una función llamada `request()`, en este caso tienes que pasarle una instancia de `Request` que en tu caso es `$request`.

`Auth::attempt()` requiere de un array asociativo en el que se le pase un array de la siguiente forma: `['Nombre del campo de identificacion' => 'valor', 'password' => 'valor']`. Es decir, la contraseña siempre ha de tener como llave `password`.

```
public function login(Request $request){
        $credentials = $this->validate($request,[ // Esta linea
            'correo' =>'email|required|string',
            'contra' =>'required|string'
        ]);

        $credenciales = [
            'correo' => $credentials['correo'],
            'password' => $credentials['contra']
        ];

if(Auth::attempt($credenciales)){
         return 'has iniciado sesion';
        }else{
        return 'NO INICIO SESION';
  }
}
```

La función `getAuthPassword()` tiene que estar en el modelo, además, he cambiado algunas cosas, como la clase a la que extiende:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Trabajador extends Authenticatable
{   

    public $table = 'Trabajadores';
    protected $primaryKey = 'IdTrabajador';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'correo', 'contra',
    ];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
         return $this->contra;
    }
}
```

Comment: amigo lo he probado e igual sale que NO INICIE SESION :s

Comment: Perdona, he encontrado otro fallo, en la pregunta lo he editado, comentame si asi se arregla.

Comment: amigo, lo he probado he igual el mismo problema, en la pregunta he aumentado la clase que uso para y he actualizado la parte del controlador, a ver si vez el error :s

Comment: Cambiaste el modelo de identificacion en la configuracion?

Comment: si en config/app lo cambie el User por 'model' => App\Trabajador::class,

Comment: He vuelto a editar la respuesta para cambiar la clase que extiende el modelo. Aun asi, ¿podrias pegar el config config/auth.php?

Comment: he aumentado en la pregunta con el config/auth, y sobre la clase que extiende igual no sale :s

Comment: Pues se me acaban las ideas... Salvo una última cosa. Puedes pegar el código donde registras a los usuarios? Podemos datos del usuario al que intentas loguear en la tabla?

Comment: ahi esta man el registecontroller , si deseas me podrias dar tu correo asi te doy todo el pequeño sistema, pero aun asi gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Creo que encontre el fallo, en la respuesta he cambiado el metodo login añadiendo la variable `$credenciales`, copiala tal cual y dime si asi sirve.

Comment: bien!!! Man al fin salio!! Gracias por  tu apoyo!! Al fin, estoy feliz!! Pense que nunca saldria!! Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Encantado de que haya funcionado, editare la respuesta explicando entonces el problema.

Comment: si man no te preocupes, muchas gracias :D !! (y)